# An image shows up again upon re-creation even after 'docker image ls' shows an empty result?

Tags: bash, docker

We have one existing docker image:

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
setupython   latest    3ce7423c6076   11 hours ago   1.49GB
```

Let's write a utility to remove the container and the image:

```
dockerrm ()
{
    docker container ls -a | grep -i -v CONTAINER | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I Q docker rm Q;
    docker image ls -a | grep -i -v IMAGE | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I Q docker image rm Q
}
```

Now remove them:

```
08:13:46/~/exp/docker $dockerrm
Untagged: setupython:latest
Deleted: sha256:3ce7423c60768b31c538968efc7155055312df9be2d05d459578b9372dab3564
```

They appear to be removed:

```
08:14:27/~/exp/docker $docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Now recreate the image:

```
docker build -t setupython --progress=plain .;
```

Did it get created fresh?

```
$docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
setupython   latest    3ce7423c6076   11 hours ago   1.49GB   # why 11 hours ago?
```

So why is the image still showing as created in the past?  What else would need to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note two points with your procedure :

- The command to remove an image is `docker rmi image`, not `rm`
- Dangling images, meaning layers that have no relationship to any
  tagged images, can be removed by `docker image prune`.
  A cleanup could be useful.

Reference :
[How To Remove Docker Images, Containers, and Volumes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes).

Comment: thx!  will accept in 6 .. 5 mins tik tok .  oh what do you mean by avoiding other linux tools?

Comment: I actually used `docker image rm`  to remove the image not `docker rm` . The latter was used to remove the container